# Fluent Validation triggered on classes which don't have validation defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, fluentvalidation

I'm using mvc3 + fluent validaton + ninject

I have simple controller and the model that don't have validation configured(Pager)...but fluent validation is triggered on that object too, so code breaks up and exception is thrown:

> **> Error activating IValidator{Pager}**

I looked up in source and found this method which suppose to check if it needs to validate some property or not, but it only check if values are not null:

```
bool IsValidatingProperty(ModelMetadata metadata) {
            return metadata.ContainerType != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(metadata.PropertyName);
    }
```

I suppose there are some config trick around this problem, in short: I want to FV be triggered only on objects on which I have FV rules defined...

Thanx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suggestion from Jeremy

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/workitem/7091

I found that solution to problem is not so hard:

```
    public class TestValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
    {
        private readonly IKernel Container;

        public TestValidatorFactory(IKernel container)
        {
            Container = container;
        }

        public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
        {
            var bindings = (List<IBinding>)Container.GetBindings(validatorType);
            if (bindings.Count > 0) return (IValidator)Container.Get(validatorType);
            else return null;
        }
    }
```